# Сравнение количества букв в слове с введенной цифрой

Tags: python

Должно подсчитываться количество букв, и сравниваться с введённым числом, больше или меньше, какую цифру не введи, кол-во букв будет всегда больше.

```
a = len((input("Ввод: ")))
b = input('Введите значение: ')
c = len((input("Ввод: ")))
if b == ("=="):
    print (a == c) 
elif b == (">"):
    print(a > c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = len(input("Ввод: "))
b = input('Введите значение: ')
c = int(input("Ввод: "))
if b == "==":
    print (a == c) 
elif b == ">":
    print(a > c)
```

Когда вы пишите `len` то вам выдается количество элементов в переменной(строке). Для того чтобы сравнивать количество символов с вводимым числом используйте `int(input())`

[Проверка](https://repl.it/@Cmertho/ConsiderateConcreteOperatingsystem)